# How to run independent thread

Tags: multithreading, perl, system

I want to run the another perl script from perl script. I have following requirement.

second perl script is independent should run in background.
In first perl script after running second perl script I don't want to wait for second perl script to finish because it take 1 hour.

I have tried the system() command with '&' its running the second perl script and first scripts exit also but getting the second perl script logs in same terminal.

I have tried like below.

```
system("perl script2.pl $param1 $param2 $param3 $param4 &");
```

Comment: Forget to add one thing when I am getting the second perl script log in same terminal also I am able to see below error. I am using using the tcsh shell.      "stty: standard input: Inappropriate ioctl for device"

Answer (score 0):

So you're asking how to redirect the output in `sh`?

```
system("perl script2.pl $param1 $param2 $param3 $param4 >file 2>&1 &");
```

Comment: Tried this but getting error stty: standard input: Inappropriate ioctl for device

Comment: Does this even relate to this question?